# Spring batch integration : java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.integration.file.FileReadingMessageSource cannot be cast to java.io.File

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-batch

```
@InboundChannelAdapter(value = "fileInputChannel", poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "15000"))
public MessageSource<File> fileReadingMessageSource() {

    FileReadingMessageSource source = new FileReadingMessageSource();
    source.setDirectory(new File(ftpUploadDir));
    source.setFilter(new SimplePatternFileListFilter("*.csv"));
    source.setScanEachPoll(true);

    source.setUseWatchService(true);


    return source;
}

@Transformer(inputChannel = "fileInputChannel", outputChannel = "jobChannel")
public JobLaunchRequest transform(Message<File>  file) {

    log.info( file.getPayload().toString());


    JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder()
            .addString("fileName", file.getPayload().getAbsolutePath())
            .addDate("dateTime", new Date())
            .toJobParameters();


    JobLaunchRequest request = new JobLaunchRequest(job, jobParameters);

    return request;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To help others understand and answer your question, could you please: 1. state both what is your goal and what is the problem that you face clearly 2. show when exactly the error happens and provide the stack trace 3. format the code appropriately

Comment: Please give more context to be able to help you.

Comment: Please, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need also add a `@Bean` annotation to your `fileReadingMessageSource()` method alongside with the `@InboundChannelAdapter`.

The point is that without that `@Bean` the Framework is going to create a `SourcePollingChannelAdapter` with the `MethodInvokingMessageSource` based on the result of this `fileReadingMessageSource()` method invocation.

See Spring Integration Reference Manual for more info: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.9.RELEASE/reference/html/configuration.html#annotations

Comment: Thank you Artem. I am kind of stuck at the moment.  I ran in the app in the debug mode.I could see control is getting into fileReadingMessageSource Bean , control is not moving into transform method of FileToJobTransformer .